# Is it possible to launch native apps using Microsoft bot framework?

Tags: botframework, cortana-skills-kit

I am creating a Cortana skill on the Cortana canvas, I have a button.
I wanted to know if it possible to have an 'imback' type of button to open a webpage.

Comment: what have you tried so far? Did you get any error?

Comment: Are you using .NET or Node SDK?

Comment: You can use the `openUrl` CardAction. For more info see: [Process events within rich cards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-add-rich-card-attachments#process-events-within-rich-cards)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can supply an openUrl to a card action, or even use ChannelData to send a LaunchUri command, deep linking to an application. (I haven't tried this, but I assume 'http://websitename.com' will launch in the Cortana host platform's default browser.)

```
activity.ChannelData = new {
     action = new { type = "LaunchUri", uri = "http://websitename.com"}
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Ye, for example

```
var message = context.MakeMessage() as IMessageActivity;
message.ChannelData = JObject.FromObject(new
{
    action = new { type = "LaunchUri", uri = "skype:echo123?call" }
});
await context.PostAsync(message);
```

this code will start a call with echo123 user on skype

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cortana/tutorials/bot-skills/bot-entity-channel-data